# How to select text between greater than and less than with an additional slash

Tags: regex, textpad

I'm trying to select text between `></` . Example below I want "text"

```
>text</
```

but I'm unable to do so.
tried the following but it doesn't like the slash at the end of the regex

```
\>(.*?)\<\
```

I'm trying to do this in TextPad. How is this supposed to be done?
I'm ultimately wanting to delete all text between these two characters so all I'm left with is something like: `<element></element>`

Comment: You are missing the `/`...?

Answer (score 0):

You are close.. use the following:

```
(>).*?(<\/)
```

And replace with `\1\2`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/11)

**OR**

You can use lookbehind and lookaheads:

```
(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<\/)
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/10)

Comment: thanks for reply, but it I'm getting "Cannot find regular expression:" when trying to use above expression. But maybe it's the program I'm using (TextPad)

Comment: thanks again but this is unable to be found as well. I have Regular Expression selected as well. hmmm

Comment: yes, I've tried both (>).*?(<\/)    AND   (?<=>)(.*?)(?=<\/)   but still same

Answer (score 0):

RegEx wise, you can use 3 groupings and for the replace only use the first and 3rd group: \1\3.

```
Find: (>)(.*)(</)   
Replace: \1\3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
\>(.*?)\<\/
```

The regex that you were trying would actually have given error because you had a `\` and nothing after that.